# Generator/Async lambda

Tags: python

Is there a prettier way to do this?

```
asyncio.coroutine(lambda: None)()
```

I want to get a dummy coroutine (generator object) to use in a one-line `if` expression inside a `gather` argument list, e.g.

```
data = asyncio.gather(
    some_coro() if some_condition else asyncio.coroutine(lambda: None)(),
    # ...more of this
)
```

in order to retain result indices:
    `data[0]`, `data[1]`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `asyncio.sleep`

```
data = asyncio.gather(
    some_coro() if some_condition else asyncio.sleep(0),
    # ...more of this
)
```

`asyncio.sleep` also have `result` kw attribute if you want return something specific instead of None